# Passar o valor de uma function post para outra function?

Tags: jquery, funções

```
 $(function(){
 $("#for").submit(function() {

    var situa = null;
    $.post("url", {dado: "campo"}, function(val) {

      if(val == 1){

       situa = 'você não foi selecionado';

           }else{

      situa = 'você foi selecionado';}



        });




   alert(situa);


    });
        });
```

Infelizmente o valor esta retornando null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variável `situa` só existe no escopo da função que é executada no retorno do envio do post. Se fosse imprescindível passar pra outra função essa variável teria que ser declarada globalmente, mas mesmo assim sua atribuição teria que esperar o ajax retornar com alguma coisa.

Fiz um exemplo de teste para exemplificar:

**index.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
variavelglobal="";

$(function()
{
    $("#botao").click(function() 
    {
        //alert( $("#campo").val() );

        $.post( 
            "paginateste.php", 
            { dado: $("#campo").val() }, 
            function(data) 
            {
                if(data==1)
                {
                    situa = 'você foi selecionado';
                }
                else
                {
                    situa = 'você não foi selecionado';
                }

                //alert(situa);           // aqui funcionaria ok desde o início

                variavelglobal = situa;   // passando valor pra variavel global
            }
        );

        //essa execução pode ocorrer antes do ajax post ter terminado, 
        // esse atraso de 100 microsegundos é proposital pra não dar alert em branco com valor vazio
        window.setTimeout
        (
            function()
            {
                alert(variavelglobal);
            },
            100
        );          

    });
});


</script>

<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" />
<input type="button" value="Enviar" id="botao">
```

**paginateste.php**

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.post("url", {dado: "campo"}).done(function(val) {
     var situa;
      if(val == 1){
       situa = 'você não foi selecionado';
           }else{
      situa = 'você foi selecionado';}
        });

   alert(situa);
)};
```

Não é aconselhável utilizar uma atribuição de NULL ao declarar uma variável em JS, já que é automaticamente atribuída um valor de Undefined para ela quando criada.